# Actualizar campo con datos de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito actualizar un campo con valores que ya tiene otro campo

tengo este script

```
UPDATE [Tabla2].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes]
SET peso = T2.peso
FROM [Tabla2].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] T1,  [Tabla1].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] T2
WHERE T1.codlote = T2.codlote
```

que actualiza el campo peso pero al ejecutarlo me pone todos los pesos igual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven lo que necesito es que me actualice los pesos en orden según el animal, no que me ponga el primer peso en todos

Comment: Te falla porque haces WHERE T1.codlote = T2.codlote y codlote son iguales, ahí se lía. prueba a hacer WHERE T1.animal = T2.animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu condicion de join esta mal.. si solo joineas por el campo codlote, en el cual son todos lo mismo, va a actualizar con el primer valor que encuentre.

Tu condicion de join deben ser codlote y animal, de la siguiente forma:

```
T1.codlote = T2.codlote and t1.animal = t2.animal
```